# MVC 3 validation messages not shown due ModelState lost after PartialView

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, fluentvalidation-2.0

I have an MVC 3 project where I have 1 view LoginRegister which contains 2 views with forms for login and pre-register. The problem is after incorrectly completing the pre-register form and using PartialView("LoginRegister", loginRegisterViewModel) validation messages aren't displayed due the ModelState being lost. Before reading the next paragraph it's probably best to jump to the **CODE**.

Debugging the PartialView("LoginRegister", loginRegisterViewModel) and stepping into the PreRegister view to the following @Html.ErrorMessageFor(model => model.Email). Where the ModelState does not contain the Email key (see below) and hence doesn't display an error message.

```
    private static MvcHtmlString ErrorMessageHelper(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, ModelMetadata modelMetadata, string expression, string validationMessage, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    {
        string modelName = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(expression);

        if (!htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState.ContainsKey(modelName)) // ModelState contains no keys, e.g. Email not found and a null is returned
        {
            return null; 
        }

        // code continues here to render error message
    }
```

### CODE

**ViewModels**

**LoginRegisterViewModel**

```
namespace Site.ViewModels.Account
{
    public class LoginRegisterViewModel
    {
        public bool IsDialog { get; set; }
        public PreRegisterViewModel PreRegister { get; set; }
        public QuickLoginViewModel QuickLogin { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**PreRegisterViewModel**

```
using FluentValidation.Attributes;
using Site.ViewModels.Validators;

namespace Site.ViewModels.Account
{
    [Validator(typeof(PreRegisterViewModelValidator))]
    public class PreRegisterViewModel
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string ConfirmEmail { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Views**

**LoginRegister**

```
@model Site.ViewModels.Account.LoginRegisterViewModel

@{
    Layout = ViewBag.Layout;
}

<div id="loginReg" class="mod-loginReg">
    <h2>Login and Registration</h2>
    @{Html.RenderPartial("PreRegister", Model.PreRegister, new ViewDataDictionary());}
    @{Html.RenderPartial("QuickLogin", Model.QuickLogin, new ViewDataDictionary());}
</div>
```

**PreRegister**

```
@using Site.Classes.MVC.Extensions;

@model Site.ViewModels.Account.PreRegisterViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("PreRegister", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-errorContainer" }))
{
    <div class="mod-loginReg-register">
        <h3>Register</h3>
        <p>Please enter your email address to register.<br /><br /></p>

        <div class="mod-loginReg-form">
            <div class="field-item">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @maxlength = "255", @class = "Textbox required email" })
                @Html.ErrorMessageFor(model => model.Email)
            </div>
            <div class="field-item">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmEmail)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ConfirmEmail, new { @maxlength = "255", @class = "Textbox required email" })
                @Html.ErrorMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmEmail)
            </div>
            <div class="button-group">
                @Html.Button("Register", "Register")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**AccountController**

```
    [RequireHttps]
    public ActionResult LoginRegister(int showDialog)
    {
        var loginRegisterViewModel = new LoginRegisterViewModel();

        if (showDialog == 1)
        {
            ViewBag.Layout = "~/layouts/structure/dialog.cshtml";
            loginRegisterViewModel.IsDialog = true;
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Layout = "~/layouts/structure/2column.cshtml";
        }

        return PartialView(loginRegisterViewModel);
    }

    [RequireHttps]
    public ActionResult PreRegister()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [RequireHttps]
    public ActionResult PreRegister(PreRegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return PartialView("PreRegisterComplete");
        }

        var loginRegisterViewModel = new LoginRegisterViewModel { PreRegister = model, QuickLogin = new QuickLoginViewModel() };

        return PartialView("LoginRegister", loginRegisterViewModel);
    }
```

Comment: Is the model state empty on the HttpPost? Also shouldnt your LoginRegister method return view and not partial view

Comment: Hi @Jon, the model state is fine and what I expect on the HttpPost. Changing the LoginRegister method to return View has no affect on the error messages.

Comment: Does the post contain the posted model values?

Comment: @Jon: Yes please see attached screen shots

Comment: @Jon: Sorry I can't attach images not enough points yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by the `viewData` being cleared out when `new ViewDataDictionary()` is called.

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("PreRegister", Model.PreRegister, new ViewDataDictionary());}
@{Html.RenderPartial("QuickLogin", Model.QuickLogin, new ViewDataDictionary());}
```

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewdatadictionary.aspx) ViewDataDictionary is used for:

> Represents a container that is used to pass data between a controller
>   and a view.

I assume you have a good reason for this otherwise you would not have taken the trouble to add the additional parameter.

If you change it to:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("PreRegister", Model.PreRegister)
@Html.RenderPartial("QuickLogin", Model.QuickLogin)
```

the `ModelState` built up in the controller should be available on your views.

Comment: Thanks Philip I removed the new ViewDataDictionary() and the validation now triggers. I left this in from an old implementation while playing. Thanks again